# Limit of this power function when the base tends to infinity

Tags: limits

Here is the function:

$$
y = b^{b^{-2}}
$$

It seems $\lim _{b \rightarrow \infty} y = 1$, but how do you prove this?

Comment: When the base and exponent varies a trick is take logarithm

Comment: @qed  i have fixed my error,right it is approaching to one after taking logarithm of both side and  calculate limit of right side equation using  well known L'Hôpital's rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write 
$$
y=b^{b^{-2}}=e^{b^{-2}\log b}
$$
and observing that, using l'Hôpital's rule, 
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{\log b}{b^2}=\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{1}{2b^2}=0$$
and finally
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}b^{b^{-2}}=e^0=1.$$

Comment: i have fixed my error

Answer (score 1):

Taking log both sides you have :

$$ \ln y = \lim_{b\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln b}{b^2}$$

We know that $\ln b$ grows much much slowly compared to that of $b^2$ , so as $b$ approaches $\infty$ it the RHS approaches 0 and hence $\ln y = 0 $ and $y =1$

Answer (score 0):

aa i understand  ,,then it is very simple ,ones again take log on both side ,we get

$log(y)=log(b)/(b^2)$,because  second part is infinity over infinity ,take L'Hôpital's rule,but i  think  that is it approaching to $0$,not $1$,please check carrefuly,you are geting $y=e/b^2$,sorry i have made mistake

right  $ln(y)=0$ and $y=1$,sorry i forgot that $y$ was in $ln$ function